# Android Eclipse App Crashes on Launch

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to developing for Android and I'm having trouble launching my project. Whenever I launch it, it crashes and I get an error. I've put breakpoints throughout my code but it crashes before it reaches them. Here is the output from LogCat:

```
07-18 18:22:17.695: I/System.out(32229): Sending WAIT chunk
07-18 18:22:17.695: W/ActivityThread(32229): Application com.amvara.skatometer is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
07-18 18:22:17.945: I/dalvikvm(32229): Debugger is active
07-18 18:22:18.095: I/System.out(32229): Debugger has connected
07-18 18:22:18.095: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:18.295: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:18.500: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:18.700: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:18.900: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:19.100: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:19.300: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:19.500: I/System.out(32229): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-18 18:22:19.705: I/System.out(32229): debugger has settled (1434)
07-18 18:22:19.735: W/dalvikvm(32229): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/amvara/skatometer/ItemListActivity; (29)
07-18 18:22:19.735: W/dalvikvm(32229): Link of class 'Lcom/amvara/skatometer/ItemListActivity;' failed
07-18 18:22:19.745: D/AndroidRuntime(32229): Shutting down VM
07-18 18:22:19.745: W/dalvikvm(32229): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410d62a0)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.amvara.skatometer/com.amvara.skatometer.ItemListActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amvara.skatometer.ItemListActivity
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amvara.skatometer.ItemListActivity
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
07-18 18:22:19.780: E/AndroidRuntime(32229):    ... 11 more
```

I can't figure out why this would happen because it isn't even hitting a breakpoint in my code. It must be a problem in the auto-generated Android code. Here's my AndroidManifest.xml, if you need it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amvara.skatometer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.amvara.skatometer.ItemListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.amvara.skatometer.ItemDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_item_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".ItemListActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ItemListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.amvara.skatometer.Bottom_panel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bottom_panel" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.amvara.skatometer.General"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_general" >
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.amvara.skatometer.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post onCreate() of ItemListActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean your project, then you can also change :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.amvara.skatometer.ItemListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >

[...]
        </activity>
```

By

```
<activity
            android:name=".ItemListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >

[...]
        </activity>
```

It append to me one time but after all modification, doesn't work so I recreate the project from scratch and imported all my class, layout, etc. At the end, works as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, cleaning my project didn't work. I tried rebuilding it, though, and now it's finally working. Thanks for your help.